How do you pass an argument for use in mutate(...) into a function?
Here is a toy example:
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  colA = runif(100),
  colB = runif(100),
  colC = runif(100)) |>
mutate(
  relevant = colB
) 

I would like to be able to wrap the above in a function and specify which column is assigned to relevant in a function argument. So e.g. foo(colB) would run the above code, but foo(colA) and foo(colC) would also work.
I know I can work around this by passing a string and using the df["colB"] syntax, but the actual code I am applying this to is part of a longer pipe and I would prefer not to break the pipe.

Short answer: wrap it in {{, so define foo = function(col) {... mutate(relevant = {{col}})}. Long answer, have a look at the linked FAQ or the vignette on programming with dplyr.
